# Is there a software for writing anywhere on the system with a pen/stylus on the touchscreen?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen, touchscreen, stylus

I'd like to write on top of my PDFs used for making presentations on my laptop with touchscreen. I do not need to save what I write, but I would like to circle or underline things, possibly write some equations, etc. and then erase them and move on.

Drawing tablets bring software of the sort I speak. Anything out there I could use with my Ubuntu 14.04? Thanks!

Comment: xournal? http://xournal.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Read this blog here: http://www.gnurou.org/blog/2008/09/09/finally_real_pdf_annotating_under_linux It recommends using PDF X-Change Viewer for Windows under Wine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software to utilize digital pen on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331638/software-to-utilize-digital-pen-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 4):

Since this question still comes up in the latest search results I want to let you know that it's possible to do more than one Freehand stroke with Okular.

You just have to double click the annotation icon (for example freehand stroke). This also works for the Highlight and Other Annotation Tools as well.

However, I still could not find out how to use the pen only for annotating and the touch screen for navigation through the document...

Comment: Thanks for the double-click tip ! 
Unfortunately freehand lines drawn with my wacom stylus suffer for a very ugly rendering (lots of "shards" parasiting the line). They are very clean and smooth in xournal so it has something to do with KDE and/or Okular and couldn't fix it KDE Wacom configuration tool :-(

Answer (score 2):

I 'll recommend you to try Okular. It gives you lots of such options to edit your pdf files.
Open your pdf using Okular and 
press  <kbd>F6</kbd> or

> Tools --> Review

It will show some tabs on the left side. Selecting these will enable you to do many functions such as underline, highlight, freehand line, ellipse, polygon, etc. Using  freehand line option, you can write on your pdf. You can even edit these functions.

To install Okular, type these commands in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install Okular
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently one of the best software I'm using in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

**Gromit-MPX** gives me better exposure in online teaching to underline or draw something during class. I just have to press <kbd>F9</kbd> and my mouse cursor becomes a pen and to reverse back again press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

It also has more functionality. It is also available in Ubuntu Store.

Comment: Also check out http://xournalpp.github.io

Comment: Really cool software but the cursor is messed up on my screen that makes it look bad.  Don't know how to fix it...

Comment: Oh I fixed that by editing the cursor file in `src/`.  It's a `.xpm` file which is a text file and I made the cursor very small and the problem is gone.  Love this software!!!

Comment: This software pen is **pressure-sensitive** which works for my pen.  The other alternatives don't have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Xournal++](https://xournalpp.github.io/), the note taking app as an annotating tool. You can **write on PDFs with mouse and digital pen**, erase text and images, insert text, insert images, insert equations with LaTeX, and do many more things.

[image: xournalpp]

To install it in Ubuntu 18.04-21.10, you can use the [Xournal++ stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/xournalpp-stable) PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/xournalpp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

In Ubuntu 22.04 and above, you can install it from the repositories (although the PPA still hosts updated versions).

```
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

You can also use the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/xournalpp) and [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.xournalpp.xournalpp) versions, but they may have issues with LaTeX.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the freehand annotation for Okular allows only one continuous line at a time. Cannot write with a pen with Okular.

Allowing pen writing on Okular would be a killer feature for the program. Until that is implemented, I'm opening PDFs in Xournal, which is an amazing, stable, powerful notetaking program in its own right

Comment: It is possible to write freehand in Okular, as per the answer by @tuxflo. You might wish to update your answer?