# How can xp pen deco mini 7 installed on ubuntu? Please mention ubuntu version it supports too

Tags: drivers, tablet

How can xp pen deco mini 7 graphic tablet installed on ubuntu? Please mention ubuntu version it supports too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: I asked about ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to https://www.xp-pen.com/product/613.html, Ubuntu 14.04-20.04 support it (and later versions may support it too).

In case it is not recognized, you would need to download the driver from https://www.xp-pen.com/download-525.html.
Here is the [download link](https://www.xp-pen.com/download/file/id/1949/pid/525/ext/zip.html) for the .deb installer.

Afterwards, have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1331667/124466) for software to utilize your graphics tablet.