# How to write on openboard with veikk pentablet?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, dependencies, hardware, stylus

I was able to install openboard but I couldn't write with my stylus "veikk-pentablet". How can I make it work?

Comment: @guiverc pelase check now! I've edited it

Comment: Can you control the mouse cursor with your tablet? That is, does the computer recognize it? If the computer does not recognize the graphics tablet, please post the output of `lsusb` with and without the tablet attached.

Comment: yes! am able to control using the mouse. is "1sus"b is a command to be done on terminal? @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: If you can control the mouse, then your tablet is detected, and you don't have to post the output of `lsusb`. What happens when you try to draw on openboard on your tablet? Alternatively, use [xournal++](https://askubuntu.com/a/1331667/124466) instead.