# How to run RTSY pen tablet on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation

I have recently purchased an RTSY pen tablet. It has a Windows driver but it doesn't have Ubuntu 20.04 drivers. Is there any way I could make it work on Ubuntu 20.04?

Model name is RTSY WP960

Comment: Once you have configured the drivers, check out https://askubuntu.com/q/1331638/124466

Answer (score 5):

That particular tablet is a rebranded “Digimend”, which can use the Wacom drivers. You’ll need to do a bit of tweaking, though:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Install the Wacom drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom
   ```
3. Create a config file for the tablet (so it’s not recognized as a mouse):

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-tablet.conf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor. It does not need to be `vi`, but you must be able to save the file as `root`.</sup>
4. Paste this into the file:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "Tablet"
     Driver "wacom"
     MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
     MatchUSBID "6161:4d15"
   EndSection
   ```
5. Save the file
6. Reboot

After the system comes back up, you’ll be able to use exactly 1/2 of the tablet … because it’ll be in “Android Mode”. To use the entire drawing surface, hold the left and right buttons (not the middle) for 6 seconds. You will see a green light turn red. Once this is done, you can use the entire drawing surface.