# To Run RTSY WP9620 graphics tablet on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, tablet

I have a RTSY Garphics Tablet WP9620. It works perfectly fine in windows, however I want to use it in Ubuntu 20.04. The drivers for this tablet are available only in Windows and MacOS. Is there any way that I can use it in Ubuntu20.04. I have searched this tablet name in both Digimend and Wacom Linux project, but it is nowhere listed.

There is a similar question on askUbuntu for RTSYWP960. I tried the commands mentioned there:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom

sudo gedit/etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/50-tablet.conf
```

But it shows that

```
sudo: gedit/etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/50-tablet.conf: command not found
```

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1361816/1222991) might give you what you’re looking for 

Comment: What is the link to the other question?

Comment: There is a typo in your command.  It should read `sudo gedit /etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/50-tablet.conf` (Note the space after `gedit`)